# Test Driven Development - What exactly is the test?

Tags: tdd

I've been learning what TDD is, and one question that comes to mind is what exactly is the "test". For example, do you call the webservice and then build the code to make it work? or is it more unit testing oriented?

Comment: I recommend editing the title to be a question. E.g. Test Driven Development - What exactly is the test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general the test may be...

- [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) which tests an individual subcomponent of your software without any external dependencies to other classes
- [integration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) which are tests that test the connection between two separate systems, ie. their integration capability
- [acceptance test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing) for validating the functionality of the system

...and some others I've most likely temporarily forgotten for now.

In TDD, however, you're mostly focusing on the unit tests when creating your software.

Answer (score 7):

It's entirely Unit Test driven.

The basic idea is to write the unit tests first, and then do the absolute minimum amount of work necessary to pass the tests.

Then write more tests to cover more of the requirements, and implement a bit more to make it pass.

It's an iterative process, with cycles of test writing, and then code writing.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of good articles by Unclebob

[Three rules of TDD](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd)

[TDD with Acceptance and Unit tests](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2007/10/17/tdd-with-acceptance-tests-and-unit-tests)

Comment: Second link is now dead...fyi.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you not to emphasize on **Test** because TDD is actually is a software development methodology, not a testing methodology.

Comment: Who down voted this?  He's right.  The point of TDD is to get you thinking about the application in small manageable units. The tests and test framework are just tools to get you thinking right.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is about unit testing and code coverage. It is about shipping bugless code and being able to make changes easily in the future.

See Uncle Bob's [words of wisdom](http://www.objectmentor.com/omSolutions/dialogs/practice_ttd.html).

Answer (score 1):

How I use it, it's unit testing oriented.  Suppose I want a method that square ints I write this method :

```
int square(int x) { return null; }
```

and then write some tests like :

```
[Test]
TestSquare() 
{
Assert.AreEqual(square(0),0);
Assert.AreEqual(square(1),1);
Assert.AreEqual(square(10),100);
Assert.AreEqual(square(-1),1);
Assert.AreEqual(square(-10),100);
....
}
```

Ok, maybe square is a bad example :-)

In each case I test expected behaviour and all borderline vals like maxint and zero and null-value (remember you can test on errors too) and see to it the test fails (which isn't hard :-)) then I keep working on the function until it works.

So : first a unit test that fails an covers what you want it to cover, then the method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which language is your example in? I'm guessing it's not Java but I can't tell which it is.

Comment: Just pseudo.  Mostly C# I guess

Answer (score 0):

Generally, unit tests in "TDD" shouldn't involve any IO at all.

In fact, you'll have a ton more effectiveness if you write objects that do not create side effects (I/O is almost always, if not always, a side effect!), and define your the behavior of your class either in terms of return values of methods, or calls made to interfaces that have been passed into the object.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give my view on the topic which may help to understand TDD a bit more in a different way.

TDD is a design method that relies in testing first. because you asked about how the test is, ill go like this:

If you want to build an application, you know the purpose of what you want to build and you know generally that when you are done, or along the way you need to test it e.g check the values of variables you create by code inspection, of quickly drop a button that you can click on and will execute a part of code and pop up a dialog to show the result of the operation etc.

on the other hand TDD changes your mindset and i'll point out one of such ways. commonly , you just rely on the development environment  like visual studio to detect errors as you code and compile and somewhere in your head, you know the requirement and just coding and testing via button and pop ups or code inspection. I call this style SDDD (Syntax debugging driven development ).
but when you are doing TDD, is a "semantic debugging driven development " because you write down your thoughts/ goals of your application first by using tests (which and a more dynamic and repeatable version of a white board) which tests the logic (or "semantic") of your application and fails whenever you have a semantic error even if you application passes syntax error (upon compilation).

Answer (score 0):

by the way even though i said "you know the purpose of what you want to build ..", in practice you may not know or have all the information required to build the application , since TDD kind of forces you to write tests first, you are compelled to ask more questions about the functioning of the application at a very early stage of development rather than building a lot only to find out that a lot of what you have written is not required (or at lets not at the moment). you can really avoid wasting your precious time with TDD (even though it may not feel like that initially)